# Missing Pages (Drafts?)

Tags: pages

When I go to "All Pages" it tells me:

All (29) | Published (24) | Bin (1)

but when I click on All it only shows me the 24 published pages, not the 29 pages it thinks are there (which I believe are draft material pages yet to be published).

Searching on the site does not find any reference to them.  Can anyone tell me if they are still there and can be recovered?

Geoff

Comment: You can check if they're still there by searching the database directly using phpMyAdmin. Also, this issue may be caused by some code --in a plugin or theme-- that is run on "pre_get_posts" action and excludes all drafts from the posts query. Deactivating plugins and using the default theme may help you debugging the issue.